# How can I make URLs to music files play in VLC on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, url, mp3, vlc

I have MP3s and other file formats that I want to provide through my website to iPhone and iPad users. VLC's iOS app seems to fit the bill, but they say

```
Additionally, third party websites and apps 
may include links to open streams directly in VLC for iOS.
```

[Here is the official documentation provided](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aIOS/#Downloads_from_the_Web)

How can I do that? I can't seem to find any documentation about it. I'm considering making a custom app just to accomplish it, but that seems silly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from VLC 2.0.2 you can use a link of type:
`vlc://path/to/file` to have the device open VLC if it is installed.

Also check the [VideoLAN forums here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=112372)

Comment: I'm actually sending the file back in response to a form POST. Is there a way to just send the "audio/x-mpeg" MIME type and cause the link to be opened by VLC?

Comment: I would return a token from the POST and then I would do a GET and call `vlc://http://your/service?token=xyz`. Since your user would be redirected to vlc I think you should grand him/her a token that may expire after some time, so he can play/pause/rewind and not lose the privilege to do so while inside vlc.