# How to stream video to VLC from direct video link (for Android or iPhone)

Tags: android, stream, vlc, smartphone

Hi I'm finding a way to create a website link to stream my direct video link from my web server to my android phone

for example I have a video direct link like :

```
http://1.1.1.1/video.mkv
```

I would like to create a web page to have like a button when press and it's automatically call VLC and stream the link above.

What I've try is just use a normal hyperlink like

```
<a href='http://1.1.1.1/video.mkv'>Play video</a>
```

when I press it's just downloading the video instead of playing it

But When I try it on mp4 video

```
<a href='http://1.1.1.1/video.mp4'>Play video</a>
```

It can call my VLC and stream it

So then I try to insert the direct link of the MKV video file 
direct to vlc by open VLC app  and open network stream 
then MKV can stream just fine

So how can I make a hyperlink to automatically call VCL to stream my MKV file without having to copy the link then open VLC and input directly to app itself everytime?

Someone Please Help

Thank You

Comment: Did you Try with openUrlIntent?

Answer (score 2):

*edit, see here:

[How can I make URLs to music files play in VLC on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383470/how-can-i-make-urls-to-music-files-play-in-vlc-on-ios)

Here is another type of example which opens an app or links to appstore if the app is not installed.

http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/25539969-How-to-Deeplink-to-Your-Mobile-App-from-Your-Website